# Install ,Upgrade and Patch Vs Fresh and Clean installation

Tags: installation, updates

For a given software, which type of installation you prefer and why?

Comment: Should this question be marked as community wiki?

Comment: I'm not specific to windows or firefox.

Comment: You're not, but that's what gets reinstalled the most :)

Comment: "For a given software", then you should actually give it, because it depends for each one. There is no common point, as it depends on how each developers made it. The only "common" that can be told is "it's better to reinstall, fresh install is always the best", but that one is obvious, simply. If you want something more precise, precise your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a fresh install usually gives you the best performance. However, it also means wasting a lot of time reconfiguring everything and making them work like before.

Upgrade and patch is the easiest way to do it, but I've sometimes had a lot of problems with this approach (especially with Firefox). The big advantage is that all the settings are kept intact (if the patcher or installer is worth anything). I've recently upgraded a Windows Vista install to Windows 7 and everything worked **extremely well**; all the software was in place, all the drivers were working. If I'd have to do it again, I'd go the same route.

Answer (score 0):

Thats's really vague. For an OS, slipstreaming patches pre-install tends to save time, but no matter what, you'll want to patch. I suppose the same is true for anything, So.. both.  I prefer a nice slipstreamed install disk, with patches once thats done, and fresh installs ONLY as needed.Life's too short for constant reinstalls ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depends, do you have an example?  This should also be a community wiki if the original question is clarified.